# Scala - type mismatch; found Int, required String

Tags: scala

I have a problem with type mismatch in Scala.
 Compiler returns an error:

> error: type mismatch;  found   : Int  required: String
>             val v3:Int = (v1+v2)

This is code of my function:

```
    def sumMaps[T, Int](m1: Map[T, Int], m2: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int] = {
        val sameKeys = m1.keySet.intersect(m2.keySet)
        var m3: Map[T, Int] = m1 ++ m2
        for (key <- sameKeys) {
            val v1:Int = m1(key)
            val v2:Int = m2(key)
            val v3:Int = (v1+v2)
            //val v:Int = (m1(key) + m2(key))
            m3 = m3 updated (key, v3)
        }
    m3
}
```

Why? Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are redeclaring `Int` as a type parameter when it is a concrete type.

You should change the method head to:

```
def sumMaps[T](m1: Map[T, Int], m2: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int] = {
```

When `Int` is a type parameter, the compiler replaces `(v1+v2)` with a string addition, so it becomes `(v1.toString + v2.toString)`, this gave you the problem.

**UPDATE**

I came up with a simpler solution to your problem:

```
def sumMaps[T](m1: Map[T, Int], m2: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int] = {
  (for (key <- m1.keySet ++ m2.keySet) yield {
    val v1: Int = m1.getOrElse(key, 0)
    val v2: Int = m2.getOrElse(key, 0)
    key -> (v1 + v2)
  }).toMap
}
```

Or an even simpler one:

```
def sumMaps[T](m1: Map[T, Int], m2: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int] = {
  (m1 ++ m2).transform {
    case (key, _) => m1.getOrElse(key, 0) + m2.getOrElse(key, 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3858210 Yes, the part in the square brackets before the parentheses in the method definition lists names which you will use to refer to **generic** types in your method. The only generic type you are using is `T`, whereas `Int` is a concrete type, so there's no need to list it in the square brackets.

Comment: @David Frank
Thank you. Earlier I wrote subMap[T, U], but I decided to change U to Int. This caused my error. But Scala Compiler named this error so indistinctly then I coudn't find it. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @user3858210 Please have a look at my update, it might be useful.