# Type mismatch, found Int required String

Tags: scala

I'm having a strange issue. I'm trying to write a simple implicit class:

```
private implicit class CounterMap[A](map: Map[A, Int]) {
  def updateCounter(k: A): Map[A, Int] =
    map + (k → map.getOrElse(k, 0) + 1)
}
```

but when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> error: type mismatch;
>     found   : Int(1)
>     required: String
>     map + (k → map.getOrElse(k, 0) + 1)

This post seemed similar [Scala - type mismatch; found Int, required String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318454/scala-type-mismatch-found-int-required-string), but it doesn't seem obvious to me that I've made the same mistake. I'm fairly new to using implicit classes and generics in Scala, so it's likely I'm missing something obvious here. Any help or explanation as to why I'm getting this error would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem seems to be with parenthesis. Enclose inner expression in parenthesis, as shown below:

```
map + (k -> (map.getOrElse(k, 0) + 1))
```

Other post that you mentioned had different problem. In that post, `Int` was used as type parameter, which is not the case here.

Comment: The arrow is actually fine, but your answer did reveal what was wrong with my code. The problem was that I was missing the parenthesis around the addition operation. If you edit that, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I thought `→` was copy / pasted from somewhere. Good to know that it worked for you.

Comment: [`scala.Predef.ArrowAssoc.→` is defined as an alias for `scala.Predef.ArrowAssoc.->`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L254), and has been there for a long time. [It was added in 2008, together with a syntax change that allows `←` to be used interchangeably with `<-` in `for` comprehension generators](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/fb80a94f674df4dbf1c2e391c126a31861e01e27).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that. Updated my answer.