# Scala requires String: Question about Scala generics

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, fold

I'm following the excellent [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason, and had a question to what I find is odd/unexpected behaviour.

I have defined a `foldRight` function like so

```scala
def foldRight[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A,B) => B): B = 
  l match {
    case Nil => z
    case x :: xs => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f)) 
  }
```

that works fine as long I pass in concrete arguments, e.g.:

```scala
foldRight((1 to 10).toList, 0)(_ + _)
val res6: Int = 55
```

If I define a similar function that takes the generic list

```scala
def sum[A](as: List[A]): Int = foldRight(as, 0)(_ + _)
```

something odd happens

```scala
  def sum[A](as: List[A]): Int = foldRight(as, 0)(_ + _)
                                                      ^
fold.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
```

Initially, I was super puzzled by this error message given the only types in play are `A`, `B` and `Int`. However, would seem it simply attempts to make sense of `+` and generic `A`'s by calling `.toString` on them as I [read about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318454/scala-type-mismatch-found-int-required-string).

If that is the case though, why come it doesn't simply adds *a<sub>1</sub>.toString + a<sub>2</sub>.toString + ... + a<sub>n</sub>.toString + 0* = `something0`? String concatenation between `String` and `Int` in Scala is fully understood by the compiler.

Hope someone can help clarifying what's happening here.

Comment: How do you expect to sum a list of generic `A`? What if I give you a **List** of **Maps** of **Users**? That should give you an idea of what is wrong. Now, for the specific error message `(_ + _)` is expanded as `(x: A, y: Int) => x + y`, since we do not know anything of **A** all we can assume is that is has the same methods of **Any**, which does has a `+` method _(due freaking **Java**)_ which also takes an **Any** and returns an **String**. So `x + y` gives an **String**, but the compiler expected a function from `(A, Int) => Int`, thus the error.

Comment: At this moment, you simply can not write that function. Latter, you will learn about **typclasses** and you will be able to write this function in terms of any **A** that behaves as a **Number**.

Comment: Super helpful and clarifying answer, thank you, Luis!

Comment: look at [scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html) and filter members by inheritance to find the `+` method

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't think we can even assume A has the same methods as Any.

Comment: @Saskia Technically speaking no. Practically speaking yes, because anything has to have all the method of **Any** _(but they may throw exceptions, like for `null`, or you may never get an actual value to call the methods, like with **Nothing**)_. Also, I believe there is an implicit conversion from **A** to **Any** always in scope.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah, thank you. Didn't know I could call .toString on it. (just tried it). I guess, because I never had to.

Answer (score 1):

> However, would seem it simply attempts to make sense of + and generic A's by calling .toString

This is not what happens. The result is similar, but it's not calling `.toString`. You found the underlying problem though.

The sum function operates on a generic `A` on which you want to call the `+`method on.

But A doesn't have a `+` method (Remember that `+` in infix position is the same as `x.+(y)`). The compiler then searches the *implicit scope* for a function or class constructor to convert this A into something that has a `+` method. It finds it in  [any2stringadd](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.11/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html).

Your method actually looks like

```
def sum[A](as: List[A]): Int = foldRight(as, 0)(any2Stringadd(_) + _)
```

Now the error makes sense. Because the + method of the any2Stringadd class expects a string as its argument. But your `z` argument is of type Int. You can see that, when you explicitly add the types to the inline function argument.

As other pointed out, this is not reconcilable without constraining the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't try to add instances of some type `A` that you know nothing about, since the Scala compiler gets confused and tries to implicitly turn your A objects into Strings, even though you have 0, which is an Int. However, you can get around this with typeclasses, like this.

```
trait Sum[T] {
  def id: T
  def add(_1: T, _2: T): T
}

implicit object IntSum extends Sum[Int] {
  def id = 0
  def add(i1: Int, i2: Int) = i1 + i2
}

def sum[A](as: List[A])(implicit sum: Sum[A]): A = foldRight(as, sum.id)(sum.add)
```

Here, `IntSum` is passed to the `sum` method implicitly, and its add method is used to sum your list together. You can define as many such implicit objects as you like for `Double`, `String`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's name some functions properly by thinking about what they are supposed to do:

```
def foldRight[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A,B) => B): B =
  l match {
    case Nil => z
    case x :: xs => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
  }

def sumInts(numbers: List[Int]): Int = foldRight(numbers, 0)(_ + _)

def concatStrings(strings: List[String]): String = foldRight(strings, "")(_ + _)

def concatStringRepresentations[A](as: List[A]): String = foldRight(as, "")(_ + _)
concatStringRepresentations(List(List(), List(1,2,3), List(0))) // List()List(1, 2, 3)List(0)
concatStringRepresentations(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)) // 1.02.03.0

def sumIntRepresentations[A](as: List[A]): Int = foldRight(as, 0)(_ + _)  
// --> type mismatch, found: String, required: Int, for second param of (_ + _)
```

This is what your `sum` function was probably supposed to be named.
To make it compile, we wish that there is

- a method `+: Int => Int` defined for any type, or...
- implicit conversions that convert any type to `Int` (something like `toString` with `Int`), or...
- other implicit conversions that make sense, or...
- something else, that can make this function succeed and is recognized by the compiler.

It turns out that `Any` can be implicitly converted to something that has a method `+(other: String) => String` that makes the `String` example work, but there is no implicit conversion from `Any` to something that has a method `+(other: Int) => Int`.

This could be explained in more detail and other answers already do that.

**Opinions:**

So, yes, the compiler gives a message that is confusing due to existence of implicit conversions. But let's look at the problem at hand which probably was our wishful thinking. Sometimes stuff just works like in the `concatStringRepresentations` function. It does not work in general, but in this special case with `String` it does.

Sometimes something works for a special case. And when we don't see that it is a special case, mistakes can happen, for instance when we apply it to something else.